# Applying visitor visa when sponsor visa extension has been applied

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Can anyone suggest me if I can apply visitor visa for my mother stating me as sponsor, when my visa/BRP is expiring Sep 11th, and she is planning to come Sep 28th.
I'm on ICT T2, and my visa extension is already submitted and bio-metrics appointment confirmed for Sep 5.

Since I'm sponsoring her whole trip expenses, I'm afraid if her visa may get refuse because of my insufficient BRP validity.

I have already submitted her visa application, and paused to book appointment, to get inputs/to hear similar experience from anyone.

I can provide all documents of my sponsorship (assigned until Sep 2021), application submitted and any such supporting documents of my visa extension, will they consider these supporting documents and approve my mother's visitor visa?

Comment: It would be sensible to wait until your own visa extension is confirmed. Immigration Rules V4.3(b) on funds, maintenance and accommodation provided by a third party says that the decision-maker must be satisfied the third party is not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of decision or the visitor’s entry to the UK. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules